# C#: Why won't my controller recognize [HttpGet]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using visual studio 2008 MVC Application.

I want to use [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] for two methods w/ same name.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult RsvpForm()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResponse)
{ 
    //To do: Email guestresponse
    return View("Thanks", guestResponse);
}
```

I get this error:

> Error  2   The type or namespace name 'HttpGetAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But I imported the following:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PartyInvites.Models;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc.Resources;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
```

Comment: And any errormessages or symptoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an older version of MVC.

Use:

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
```

instead